# 401 Unauthorized When I try to access API on remote access

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, war

I've do some search but nothing in my case (or who's solve). I've an API in JAVA using SpringBoot and Tomcat9, when I'm using it on local, all work but when I'm trying to put my API on my VPS, I cannot access it.

see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khCPl.png

I try to change the server port on my application.properties to 5000 but still need to access by port 8080 (5000 tell me "Could not get any response")
The upload of the war works (passing by tomcat manager).

If you need some details, asking me.

Thank's for your help.

N.B : I just see on my logs that :

> f.n.a.s.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint      : Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource

N.B2 : My SecurityConfig file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();

    // Add our custom JWT security filter
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}}
```

And application.properties :

```
## Server Properties
server.port= 5000

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username= admin
spring.datasource.password= nox

## Hibernate Properties

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

## Hibernate Logging
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG

## Jackson Properties
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS= false
spring.jackson.time-zone= UTC
```

And Application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
    ApiApplication.class,
    Jsr310JpaConverters.class
})
public class ApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApiApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter :

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: @dur Yup. localhost:5000/api/auth/signup and 163.x.xx.xxx:8080/api/auth/signup only port change, i don't know why but when i put 5000 for server.port is ignoring on 163.x.xx.xxx